# Typescript seems to miss interpret a class/type as value "'Classname' refers to a value but is used as type here"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'd like to pass an Object of a React.Component as "this" to a Child React.Component like this:

file with component 1:

```
class Comp1 extends React.Component<...,...> {
    ...
    render() {
        return (<Comp2
            comp1={this}/>)
    }
}

export default withRouter(Comp1);
```

file with component 2:

```
...
import Comp1 from "./Comp"

interface Comp2Props extends RouteComponentProps {
    ...
    comp1: Comp1; //Here it says "... refers to a value but is being used as a type here."
}

class Comp2 extends React.Component<Comp2Props,...> {
    ...
}
```

If there is information missing in the minimal example please don't hesitate to inform me. But basically all I do is passing a parent component to the child component to be able to make certain function calls on the parent from the child. How can I make TS recognize the component as a Type not as a value? (The name of the class in my project is "Home" is there some different usage of "Home" inside of TS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think passing the whole component is a good practice, if viable at all. A recommended practice would just be passing functions to the child component as props, like such:

```
class Comp1 extends React.Component<...,...> {

  doSomething () {
    // some code
  }

  doAnotherThing() {
    // more code
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <Comp2 
        doSomething={this.doSomething} 
        doSomethingElse={this.doAnotherThing}
      /> 
    )
  }
}
```

You can read more about this pattern in the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Comment: Thank you so far. I didn't even know thats possible (new to TS/JS/react). Still I would like to understand why I receive this error and how to do it if intended correctly.

Comment: Sure thing, yeah, I realized afterwards that I didn't really answer your question. But functions are much easier to type correctly.